# Archivo a crear ya existe se debe preguntar al usuario si se desea sobrescribir o guardarlo con otro nombre con Java NeatBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy creando un Bloc de Notas en Java Netbeans. He escrito el código del menú Archivo (Nuevo, Abrir.., Guardar y Guardar como...) y el menú Editar (Copiar, Cortar y Pegar).
Mi problema es que quiero que al guardar el archivo si el usuario escoge el mismo nombre que un archivo que ya existe quiero que se le pregunte si desea sobrescribir el que ya existe o guardar con otro nombre.

```
private void abrirVentanaGuardar() {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

        fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        int seleccion = fc.showSaveDialog(this.getContentPane());

        // Si hemos pulsado en OK
        if (seleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

            // Fichero seleccionado
            this.ficheroActual = fc.getSelectedFile();
            
            // Se escribe la información en el archivo
            this.escribirFichero();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Y cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: como se haría al usuario la pregunta de sobrescribir el archivo o guardar con otro nombre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo con [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3729157/236345), un camino elegante sería sobreescribir el método del JFileChooser. Algo como:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(){
    @Override
    public void approveSelection(){
        File f = getSelectedFile();
        if(f.exists() && getDialogType() == SAVE_DIALOG){
            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"The file exists, overwrite?","Existing file",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
            switch(result){
                case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                    super.approveSelection();
                    return;
                case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                    return;
                case JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION:
                    return;
                case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
                    cancelSelection();
                    return;
            }
        }
        super.approveSelection();
    }        
}

fc.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
int seleccion = fc.showSaveDialog(this.getContentPane());

// Si hemos pulsado en OK
if (seleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

    // Fichero seleccionado
    this.ficheroActual = fc.getSelectedFile();
    
    // Se escribe la información en el archivo
    this.escribirFichero();
}
```